# SMB address handling in web browsers: file:///// or file://?

Tags: browser, samba, url, smb

When a SMB share path is `\\server\dir`, if I type that in FireFox, FireFox shows the directory's content and the address showing is `file://///server/dir`. If I do that with Edge, it also shows the content, but the address is `file://server/dir/`.

What is the difference? Is one right and the other wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are valid syntactically, and I'm not sure if there is any specification stating that one version is *more correct* than the other.

Firefox's version has an empty "authority" field and puts the whole UNC path in the "path" field, implying that the UNC path is a "local" path – which is acceptable because Firefox can access it *as if it were* a local path (i.e. using only standard OS file operations) without having to parse or understand the components of the original UNC path.

```
file:  //  /  C:/Windows
file:  //  /  //server/dir
              ^-- the actual OS-level path
           ^-- URL path prefix
       ^-- URL authority prefix
^-- URL scheme
```

The [newest standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8089.html) for `file:` URLs (which mostly codifies existing ad-hoc practices) allows this usage by stating:

> Throughout this document, the term "local file" is used to describe
> files **that can be accessed through the local file system API** using
> only the information included in the file path, not relying on other
> information (such as network addresses).  It is important to note
> that a local file may not be physically located on the local machine,
> for example, if a networked file system is transparently mounted into
> the local file system.

(Remember that most Unix-like systems have no equivalent to a "UNC path" for remote files – an NFS or SMB file share must be manually mounted onto a user-selected path before it can be accessed at all, and once that's in place, paths into the NFS mount look exactly like local paths. So it would be very difficult to require the usage of `file://<hostname>/` URLs for remote paths.)

But behavior of *non-local* `file:` URLs is not part of the specification at all – it is entirely implementation-defined. So [Microsoft's interpretation](https://web.archive.org/web/20100619130018/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx) is to have the browser *understand* the components of a UNC path and to map them 1:1 to the corresponding fields of a file URL (as they have really similar semantics), and that's acceptable as well.

```
file:  //  server  /dir
                   ^-- URL path
           ^-- URL authority
       ^-- URL authority prefix
^-- URL scheme
```

---

Note that the "authority" field in URLs is syntactically optional – its presence is indicated by the two leading slashes; a fully local path *could* be specified as `file:/etc/passwd` or `file:C:/Windows` rather than the more common `file:///etc/passwd` or `file:///C:/Windows`. (KDE likes to use the shorter version.)

But if you remove the authority field when the URL path contains an UNC path (which *also* happens to start with two slashes), then the server address of the UNC path ends up becoming the new "authority" field in the URL.